# Can I unlock Crushing difficulty after beating the game on Normal?

Tags: uncharted-golden-abyss

In Uncharted: Golden Abyss, can I unlock Crushing difficulty if I beat the game on Normal or do I have to beat it on Hard to unlock it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **must** beat the game on hard difficulty in order to unlock the crushing difficulty.

Comment: crap, that's what I was afraid of. Do you know if I have to replay all the "rub dirt off this thing" segments when I replay?

Comment: Sorry, I don't know.

Comment: A couple of people now have reported that this doesn't work - is there anything besides playing on hard that you have to do?

Comment: You don't have to redo the rub the dirt or puzzles.